# Does there exist an entire function such that it transforms the real axis in the imaginary axis, and the imaginary axis into the parabola $y=x^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have been trying to solve this question for my complex analysis class, its from another year exam.

I attempted to use the Cauchy-Riemman equations to prove that there is non, but having $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ results in having either $x=0$ or $y=0$ in my inputs of the function.

I end up having that:

1. $u(x,0)=0$ $v(x,0)$ is a surjective function
2. $u(0,y)^2=v(0,y)$
3. $u(0,0)=v(0,0)=0$ as it is the intersection of the images

Then I attempted to prove that either $u$ or $v$ are not harmonic functions, but that led me nowhere for the same reason.

After trying multiple things I reach nowhere.

NOTE: An entire function is a holomorphic function in all the points of the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(z) = i\left(\alpha z - \alpha^2 z^2\right)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. *Of course, this function does not map the real axis **onto** the imaginary axis.*

Comment: does mapping mean that every point on one axis has a corresponding point on the other axis or does it mean unique (or 1:1) correspondence of points? Sorry I am new to this